# SpringBoot se rehúsa a escribir el JSON de un endpoint

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, excepciones

Estoy haciendo una API con SpringBoot, la cosa es que el endpoint
/posts
retorna todos los "posts" o publicaciones de los usuarios, en una lista de objetos JSON, aquí un ejemplo

```
[
  {
    "user": {
      "username": "hola",
      "email": "hola",
      "password": "hola",
      "hierarchy": 1,
      "id": 204
    },
    "title": "hola",
    "description": "hola",
    "id": 52
  }
]
```

pero cuando uso el endpoint /posts/{id} y pongo como id "52", el servidor lanza un error 500 y una excepción, y no entiendo por qué

```
2023-11-28T22:36:41.159-04:00  WARN 2680 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy [com.artport.artport.domain.entities.Post#52] - no Session]
```

este es el código del controlador

```
@GetMapping("/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Post> getPost(@PathVariable Long postId) {
        Post post = postService.getPost(postId);
        if (post != null)
            return ResponseEntity.ok(post);
        else
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
```

y el del servicio

```
@Override
    public Post getPost(Long postId) {
        return postRepository.getReferenceById(postId);
    }
```

y la entidad Post

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "posts")
@Builder
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long postId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
    private String title;
    private String description;
}
```

y la entidad User

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
@Builder
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Short hierarchy = 0;

}
```

lo volví a intentar esta vez retornando un PostDto en el endpoint, pero sigue dando el mismo error

```
@Override
    public PostDto getPost(Long postId) {
        Post post = postRepository.getReferenceById(postId);
        return new PostDto(post.getId(), post.getUser(), post.getTitle(), post.getDescription());
    }

@GetMapping("/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<PostDto> getPost(@PathVariable Long postId) {
        PostDto postDto= postService.getPost(postId);
        if (postDto != null)
            return ResponseEntity.ok(postDto);
        else
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, Santiago, ¿puedes incluir tu entidad Post? Parece que ese error suele darse cuando algún elemento de la entidad se carga de forma LAZY. ¿El usuario quizás?

Comment: claro, ya lo puse, lo puse sin getters y setters porque no me dejaba

Comment: qué es cargar una entidad de forma lazy?

Comment: Pues es en este caso es cargar el User solo si accedes a él. Un ejemplo tonto es que en el servicio pongas un log que escriba "Recuperado post con id " + post.id + " del usuario " + post.user.id. https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading#

Comment: La solución más rápida es que en el servicio mapees los campos que necesites en un bean básico, un PostDTO, y que sea eso lo que devuelva el endpoint.

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21708339/2553194) puedes encontrar otras opciones, que implican modificar el mapper (lo que transforma de entidad a JSON)

Comment: hice lo de los Dto pero no funcionó
Override
 public PostDto getPost(Long postId) {
  Post post = postRepository.getReferenceById(postId);
  return new PostDto(post.getId(), post.getUser(), post.getTitle(), post.getDescription());
 }

Comment: Si te sale el mismo error, puede ser porque en el dto estás almacenando una referencia a User en lugar de tener un UserDto.  Para ahorrarte los dtos, puedes probar las otras soluciones que enlacé en mi anterior comentario. Me temo que no tengo ningun proyecto con Hibernate donde hacer pruebas para ayudarte mejor